# Does $\frac{3}{1\cdot 2} - \frac{5}{2\cdot 3} + \frac{7}{3\cdot 4} - ...$ Converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\frac{3}{1\cdot 2} - \frac{5}{2\cdot 3} + \frac{7}{3\cdot 4} - ...$$

Do you have an idea about this serie? If it converges what is the sum?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}$

So,

$\frac{3}{1.2}-\frac{5}{2.3} +\frac{7}{3.4}...= \frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}....$
That should give you the idea.

Comment: I didnt understand how they are equal

Comment: Does my edit explain it?

Answer (score 2):

Use the equality
$$
\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

This is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{2 k+1}{k (k+1)}$$

For large $k$, the summand behaves as $2(-1)^k/k$.  By comparison to

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \log{2}$$

the sum converges.

Note that the sum may be expressed as

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} \left ( \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k+1} \right ) = \log{2} + (1-\log{2}) = 1$$

Comment: Please expand on the first paragraph. Comparison for non-positive series is surprisingly tricky.

Comment: Nice solution; just beware that your $(-1)^k$ should be $(-1)^{k+1}$ so what you've found is $-1 \times$ the OP's series.

Comment: @CliveNewstead: thanks.