# Uncomfortable Series Calculations (not geometric nor telescoping): $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty } (-1)^{n+1}\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the sum of the following infinite series:
$\sum_{n=1}^{ \infty } (-1)^{n+1}\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}$.
I tried to break it apart and solve like a telescoping series, but to no avail. Unless I have missed something major, it is definitely not a geometric series. The only way that I found the sum was to use Wolfram Alpha, which gave me the answer of 1. By just calculating and plugging in a bunch of numbers, I was able to see the answer tending towards 1, but I would like to know if there is an explicit way to calculate this. Any ideas?

Comment: Off the top of my head and without giving the problem any thought at all, a partial fraction decomposition seems promising.

Comment: I checked and yes it's definitely a telescoping series.  Just do the partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: $$(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n+(n+1)}{n(n+1)}=(-1)^{n+1}\frac1{n+1}-(-1)^n\frac1n$$

Comment: See also: [Does $\frac{3}{1\cdot 2} - \frac{5}{2\cdot 3} + \frac{7}{3\cdot 4} - ...$ Converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/309006) and [Sum of two harmonic alternating series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1422244).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break the sum into two parts:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty } (-1)^{n+1}\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty } (-1)^{n+1}\frac{2n}{n(n+1)}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty } (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)} \tag1$

The first sum is equal to:

$-2\sum\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty } \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+1}=\big(-2\sum\limits_{n=0}^{ \infty } \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n+1}x^{n+1}+2\big)_{x=1}=-2\ln2+2 \tag2$

At the second one using  partial fraction decomposition:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty } (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}- \sum\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}\tag3$

Start both sums from zero and using the same fact (Taylor series of ln(x+1)):

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{ \infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+2}}{n+1}- \sum\limits_{n=0}^{ \infty } \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n+1}-1=\ln2+\ln2 -1\tag4$

Summarize the results of (2) and (4)  we get:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty } (-1)^{n+1}\frac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}=1\tag5$